# Binding multiple form model to edit in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am new to laravel. May be question didnot matched the problem. Problem is that. I have database table one to many like hotel and room. One hotel can have multiple room. My goal is:

```
 public function edit($id) {
    echo $id;
    // get the hotel
    $data['hotel'] = Hotel::find($id);
    $data['rooms'] = Room::where("hotelId", $id)->get();

    // show the edit form and pass the hotel
    return view('include.middle')->nest('main', 'hotel.edithotel', $data);
}
```

I am getting data from room and hotel table. No doubt there can be multiple rooms.

In view. I want to get all the data to edit for hotel and room.

### editHotel.blade.php

```
 //for hotel
 {{ Form::model($hotel, array('route' => array('hotel.update', $hotel->hotelId), 'method' => 'PUT')) }}

 //for room.  I want to run this in loop so that I can get data to edit for multiple rooms.
 {{ Form::model($rooms, array('route' => array('room.update', $rooms->roomId), 'method' => 'PUT')) }}
```

But I am getting error as

```
 Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$roomId (View: /Users/apple/hotelbooking/resources/views/hotel/edithotel.blade.php)
```

I have set primary keys in Room and Hotel Model.

Database schema.

```
  Hotel
  hotelId  | name             | address
  1        | example hotel       somewhere

  Room
  roomId   | hotelId   |  name  | price 
  1           1           Delux    $300
  2           1           Economy  $100
```

Comment: you can post the scheme of your tables.

Comment: Ok. I will edit the question.

Comment: Have you already found the solution?

Comment: No not yet. I think I should start bounty in this question.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any problem with primary keys or any problem with laravel. 
The problem is that you, like laravel is saying, are trying to get an undefined property from a **COLLECTION**.

A collection is a Laravel object that is somehow like an array (You can read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-collections) for collections)

Now to solve you proble the only thing you need to do is to put

```
{{ Form::model($rooms, array('route' => array('room.update', $rooms->roomId), 'method' => 'PUT')) }}
```

in a foreach loop.

```
@foreach($rooms as $room)
{{ Form::model($room, array('route' => array('room.update', $room->roomId), 'method' => 'PUT')) }}
@endforeach
```

This way you will use the **object** and not the **collection**

Comment: Hi, now its throwing this error 'Declaration of App\Room::update() should be compatible with Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::update(array $attributes = Array, array $options = Array)'

Comment: It throws error because routes are also in loop. How to handle that. Is there any alternative.

Comment: The first error i think it comes because you have implemented an update() method to the Room model. rename it if you have and be careful when naming functions and methods  
For the second i would make it like this 

{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('room.update', $room->roomId), 'method' => 'PUT') }}
    @froeach($room as $r)
        //whataever you want here ex a text Form::text($r->attr)
    @endforeach
{{ Form::close() }}

Comment: room is the collection as said before. It is not possible to assign id to the routes this way. I think it is not possible to do what I want to do.

Comment: For that you can use Request model of laravel.

Comment: How would you pass id

Comment: There are multiple way of passing the id. You can use a hidden input for example. These are things you should learn by yourself. Look for some tutorials at laravel.io and since you have just started learning laravel i would recommend learning laravel 5 and up.

Comment: I am not talking about that. How would you bind each room id to the each form and each routes so that you can upadate the room data.

Comment: By the way i said you have only one form use ine input type hidden for id with name id1 for room one. Id2 for room 2 ...  and one not hidden for the value needed to be updated. And this is what you really need to learn. Don't expect to fins the solution always from others. Experiment with solutions and find the best one. Read a lot. This way you will learn.

Comment: Hey did the answer helped about you situation?

Comment: No it did not helped me. I think you are not able to catch me what is the problem of my senario.

Comment: And I ended up doing it seperate edit for seperate room.

Comment: do you have this error anymore? Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$roomId (View: /Users/apple/hotelbooking/resources/views/hotel/edithotel.blade.php)

Comment: That error is sovled but the goal to my question is not solved.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not so you can post a question and have an entire project solved. It is sobyou post some code and find out what is wrong. In your code that part was wrong.

Comment: Not only that part. My question is about binding model to multiple form to edit multiple room. But it didnot solved the problem. Anyway thank you for the responses.